# Django : AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, unicode

views.py :

```
def submit_upload(request,):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = AerialForm(request.POST)
        id_key = form.data['id_key']
        year_id = form.data['year_id']
        year = Year.objects.get(year_id=year_id)

        series_id = form['series_id'].value()
        q_series = Series.objects.get(series_id=series_id)
        s_name = q_series.series.lower()

        table_name = s_name+'_photocenter_'+year.year_name

        query = table_name.objects.filter(ID_KEY=id_key)
```

from my code above, I want to get value from `query` and when I run the code, i get this error :

```
    query = table_name.objects.filter(ID_KEY=id_key)

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: Which version of Django You have?

Answer (score 2):

To dynamic load model use:

### Django 1.7+

```
from django.apps import apps
Model = apps.get_model(app_label='your_app_name', model_name=table_name)
```

### older Django

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
Model = get_model('your_app_name', table_name)
```

### universal

```
try:
    from django.apps import apps
    Model = apps.get_model(app_label='your_app_name', model_name=table_name)
except ImportError:
    from django.db.models.loading import get_model
    Model = get_model('your_app_name', table_name)
```

Comment: i tried your code and i got this error . No module named apps

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

`table_name` should be a model name. in your case, it is just a unicode object

you need sothing like (credits go to Tomasz)

```
from django.apps import apps

model_name = '%s_photocenter_%s' % (s_name, year.year_name)
YourModel = apps.get_model(app_label='your_app_name', model_name=model_name)
```

Comment: i know what you meant but i create this variable:  table_name = s_name+'_photocenter_'+year.year_name to get the same name with my model name.